# Create dictionary of dictionary from each row and export each row as a json file in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, reshape

I have a pandas data frame that looks like below

[image]

I would like to create a dictionary of dictionaries like below for each row. traits inside a list of dictionaries.

#row1 example output. it should skip null attributes face and hat.

```
{
 "name": "rv",
 "image": "https://img0.png",
 "attributes": [
 { "trait_type": "background", "value":"grey" },
 { "trait_type": "tshirt", "value":"yellow" },
 { "trait_type": "eagle", "value":"male" },
 { "trait_type": "hair", "value":"darktwists" }
]
}
```

#row3 example output. it should skip null attributes face and hair.

```
{
 "name": "nv",
 "image": "https://img2.png",
 "attributes": [
 { "trait_type": "background", "value":"brown" },
 { "trait_type": "tshirt", "value":"americanflag" },
 { "trait_type": "eagle", "value":"male" },
 { "trait_type": "hat", "value":"policehat" }
]
}
```

Like this, each row output should be stored in a separate JSON file.

I tried this with lambda apply and _to_json and I encounter two problems:
1)not able to pack attributes as a separate dictionary inside dictionary in the required format.
2)JSON stores forward slashes "//" in HTTPS image link as '/'

Any help is much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: The JSON format you have is not a generic type format, so it can not be created directly using pandas `to_json()` and/or `to_dict()` methods of the dataframes, so you need to handle it manually

Second thing: pandas by default adds the escape character that is why `'https://img0.png'` gets replaced by `https:\\/\\/img0.png`

```py
out=(df.assign(attributes=df[['background',  'tshirt', 'eagle', 'face', 'hat']]
                        .apply(lambda x:[{'trait_type':index, 'value':value}
                                         for index, value in x[x.notna()].iteritems()],
                               axis=1))
                        [['name', 'image', 'attributes']]
                        .apply(dict, axis=1)
                        .tolist()
     )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[
    {
        'name': 'rv', 
        'image': 'https://img0.png', 
        'attributes': [
                {'trait_type': 'background', 'value': 'gray'}, 
                {'trait_type': 'tshirt', 'value': 'yellow'}, 
                {'trait_type': 'eagle', 'value': 'male'}
                ]
    }, 
    {
        'name': 'cv', 
        'image': 'https://img1.png', 
        'attributes': [
                {'trait_type': 'background', 'value': 'yellow'}, 
                {'trait_type': 'tshirt', 'value': 'green'}, 
                {'trait_type': 'eagle', 'value': 'male'}
                ]
    }
]
```

After this, you will have a list of dictionaries in the variable `out`, you can just pass it to `json.dumps` to create the json out of it, which looks like below:

```py
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(out, indent=4)
[
    {
        "name": "rv",
        "image": "https://img0.png",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "trait_type": "background",
                "value": "gray"
            },
            {
                "trait_type": "tshirt",
                "value": "yellow"
            },
            {
                "trait_type": "eagle",
                "value": "male"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "cv",
        "image": "https://img1.png",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "trait_type": "background",
                "value": "yellow"
            },
            {
                "trait_type": "tshirt",
                "value": "green"
            },
            {
                "trait_type": "eagle",
                "value": "male"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, for your explanation and answer. Exactly what i needed :)

Comment: How do I export each list value in "out" to a separate JSON file?

Comment: You will have the entire list of dictionaries in a list `out`, you just need to iterate the items in the list, and write it as json to the corresponding file, something like: `for d in out:  json.dumps(d, fi)` where `fi` represents the file buffer for each file created using for example `f1 = open('file1.txt', 'w')`

Comment: Thank You. If you could add that piece to your main reply that would be helpful for others as well :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to melt the df to structure it for `"attribute"` key in your dictionary and rename the columns accordingly:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['name','image'])
df = df.rename(columns={'variable':"trait_type"})
```

Then we need to group them based on the name and image (and other unique values you want to include in your json structure.) Then itterate over groups and constructe the dictionary structure:

```
results = []
for index, group in df.groupby(['name','image']):
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_dict["name"] = index[0]
    temp_dict["image"] = index[1]
    temp_dict["attributes"] = group[["trait_type","value"]].to_dict("records")
    results.append(temp_dict)
```

This should give you your preferred results.

**Compact Answer (Suggested by [Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus)):**

You can perform the whole operation in one line:

```
dicts = (df.melt(id_vars=['name', 'image'], var_name='trait_type')
    .dropna()
    .groupby(['name', 'image'])[['trait_type', 'value']]
    .apply(pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='records')
    .reset_index(drop=False)
    .rename(columns={0: 'attributes'})
    .to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Comment: By `id_vars=['kunta','date_q']` you probably mean `id_vars=['name','image']`? And: You don't need the `df.rename(..)`, just use the kwarg `var_name='trait_type'` in `melt`.

Comment: One last remark (sorry!): You could chain the whole operation pretty neatly (chaining is the Pandas-way): `dicts = (df.melt(id_vars=['name', 'image'], var_name='trait_type').dropna().groupby(['name', 'image'])[['trait_type', 'value']].apply(pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='records').reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={0: 'attributes'}).to_dict(orient='records')).`

Comment: Thank you for your amazing remarks @Timus! I was playing with my own df to test the code. I will update the answer as you recommended :D